# Position text inside translated element

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve such thing:

The text is located inside a half circle, which is on a card. 
The circle has a minimum width and a maximum ( in order not to full up the full card ). 
The text can be in 1 or 2 rows maximum.

I cant handle the text positioning, so it would be 10px from the card border. Any ideas?

Here is my current snippet:

```css
.list_item {
  height: 85px;
  width: 300px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  background: blue;
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width:300px;
  border-radius:99999px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.text {
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="list_item">
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="text">
        Item 1
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="list_item">
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="text">
        Item 2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="list_item">
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="text">
        Item 3 3333 3333
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the text is flying somewhere. Is there a way to achieve such things:

[image]

Or did i miss something and gone a wrong direction?

Comment: I'd suggest you separate the text from the shape otherwise you'll have a hard time positioning the text where you want it on each screen size that is if you care about responsiveness

Comment: @ZohirSalak That is the interesting part, because text can "stretch the circle"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have the text in a regular rectangular div where the content flows normally, and then append a slight curvature afterwards with a `::after` pseudo element that is set to `position: absolute` and a couple pixels past the furthest distance right

[image: Example]

#### Demo in Stack Snippets

```css
.list_item {
  height: 85px;
  width: 300px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.circle {
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px 3px 0 10px;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    background: #0000ce;
    color: white;
    max-width: 150px;
    z-index: 0;
}

.circle::after {
    content: " ";
    background: #0000ce;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    right: -20px;
    margin-top: -44px;
}
```

```html
<div class="list_item">
  <div class="circle">
      Item 1
  </div>
</div>

<div class="list_item">
  <div class="circle">
      Item 2 - Longer
  </div>
</div>


<div class="list_item">
  <div class="circle">
      Item 3 - Longer With Line Wrap
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Explanation

Just to visualize what we're working with, if we start with your CSS structure and take off `overflow: hidden` and `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`, we should get this starting point

[image]

If we add `translate(-50%, -50%)` back in, the circle will shift back and left

[image]

Even if if shift the text from the top left to the bottom right of the circle or left aligned to the outer container, I don't see a vehicle for using the text length to determine the circle's position.  Because the circle is moved to the left via `translate(-50%)`, it's position is set irrespective of the text length.

Instead, if the text is just placed inside the rectangle with `height: 100%`, it'll adjust left and right as needed

[image]

Then add the circle back in as a child of the text and pin it to the right side with `position: absolute`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is my approach to this problem, I believe it is that you wanted to achieve.

```css
.list_item {
  height: 85px;
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
   overflow: hidden; 
  position: relative;
  display:flex;
}

.circle {
    background: blue;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
}

.text {
  color: #fff;
  min-width: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 30px 0 15px;
  max-width: 300px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="list_item">
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="text">
        It was loooong helloooooo
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="list_item">
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="text">
        Half long helooo 
      </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="list_item">
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="text">
        Helooooo
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="list_item">
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="text">
        More helloo helloo helloo helloo helloo helloo 
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="list_item">
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="text">
        Even more helloo helloo hello hellohello hello Multiple lines helloo helloo hello hellohello hello
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice, yeah `border-bottom-right-radius` is a solid approach

Answer (score 0):

you may also draw the circle from a radial gradient:

give a blue background to the text container and a right padding where the curve is supposed to stand. A sibbling(tag or pseudo) filling up the room left, *-that's where flex comes handy-*, will draw the curve from a radial gradient on its far left side overlapping the text box.

example of the idea *(tune the values to your needs)*

```css
li {
  height: 85px;
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
}

li span {
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: max-content;
  padding: 10px 50px/* let room for sibling to overlap*/
  10px 10px;
  background: blue;
  color: white
}

li:after {
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: -50px;
  /* overlap previous sibling*/
  background: radial-gradient(circle at -150px -40px, blue 200px, white 201px)
}

span[class] {
  max-width: 60%;
  color:tomato
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>some text</span></li>
  <li><span>no max-width fill it to the end aaa aaa aaa</span></li>  
  <li><span class>max-width for that one only set for the demo</span></li>
  <li><span>some text <br>some text</span></li>
  <li><span>some text some text some text <br>some text</span></li>
</ul>
```